# Homebrew update error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I try to run `brew update`, I see: `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:`, then a large list of packages, and then I get the error:

`Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.

What can I do about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you installed the beta of El Capitan?

Read this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40519